# Probability or Set

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I'm really good at probability, but this time I seems like I'm not.

My friends asked me a very tricky question, and I want to see if there's anyone who can find out the answer.

Here's the question:

> In a survey of 1,000 randomly selected people:
>
> - 756 believed that the price of the particular product of is reasonable compared to the last year increase,
> - 487 believed that the quality of that product is worse than the last year, and
> - 363 believed both

From here we know:

> Product is reasonable + Product is worse = 363

But how about

- Product is reasonable + Product is not worse
- Product is not reasonable + Product is worse
- Product is not reasonable + Product is not worse

I'm trying to figure it out using set like $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$ but seems like hard for me.

Comment: Please provide explanation how u found the result

Comment: Your question is phrased in an extremely unclear manner IMHO. The title as well as the first line state **probability**, but there is no trace of this term for the remaining of the question. In the question itself, the first bullet is extremely confusing. How can you compare a price to an increase??? In your conclusions below, what do you mean `Product is reasonable + Product is worse = 363`, and how did you get to that?

Comment: I don't know the conventions round here - is the elementary-set-theory tag appropriate here? I would have said it's not.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I would argue it is as the theory behind how to find the answer deals with De'Morgans laws and inclusion-exclusion and can be visualized via a Venn Diagram, all things which appear in the description of the tag as you hover your mouse over it.  I would however argue that the other two tags (statistics and probability-distributions) are not relevant.

Answer (score 26):

For this kind of question, it's often best to make a table.  Here's the data when put into a table.

$$ \begin{array}{c|cc|c} 
&\text{ Is Reasonable } & \text{ Not Reasonable } & \text{ Total}  \\ \hline
\text{Is Worse} &363 & ??? &487 \\
\text{Is Not Worse} & ??? & ??? & ???\\ \hline
\text{Total} &756 & ??? & 1000
\end{array}$$

With the given information, you can fill in all of the question marks.